# create a graph using a Map of the U.S

Tags: graphics, sas, enterprise-guide

I have a dataset that has a list of states its cotton and corn output. I wish to create a graph of the U.S to visibility show the geographical distribution of the output. I feel I should use Graph -> Map Chart->Data (once I select the 2D map), there I am stuck.

Any help will be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose you want to create a map based on `MAPS.US` dataset. 
Your dataset with cotton and corn output should contain a common variable with `MAPS.US` that indicates state - `statecode` (or `state`).

Then, when having your dataset opened, you go to Graph -> Map Chart -> Data.

Next, edit "Map Data Source" and select `MAPS.US` dataset. Then for `statecode` variable choose the "Id" role and for `corn` or `cotton` variable the "Response" role. Note that only 1 variable can be chosen as Response.

Click "Run" and see the resulting map.